# eledmac and quote without right indentation

Tags: quoting, eledmac

I changed the definition of the `quote` environment to not indent on the right side. But this change doesn't work between `\pstart` and `\pend` of `eledmac`. How would I do that? I tried by redefing the `\quote` command from `eledmac.sty`, see the lines commented out, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\list{}{\rightmargin=0pt}\item[]}{\endlist}
%\renewcommand{\quote}{\par\leavevmode%
%                                \parindent=0pt%
%                                \skipnumbering%
%                                \ifautopar%
%                                    \vskip-\parskip%
%                                \else%
%                                    \vskip\topsep%
%                                \fi%
%                                \global\leftskip=\leftmargin%
%                                \global\rightskip=0pt%
%    }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eledmac` changes the definition of `\quote` only as part of `\beginnumbering`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
% \usepackage{etoolbox} % eledmac already loads etoolbox.

\makeatletter
\appto\initnumbering@sectcmd{%
  \ifnoquotation@\else
    \patchcmd{\quote}{\global\rightskip=\leftmargin}{\global\rightskip=0pt }{}{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

You may want to patch also `\quotation`:

```
\appto\initnumbering@sectcmd{%
  \ifnoquotation@\else
    \patchcmd{\quote}{\global\rightskip=\leftmargin}{\global\rightskip=0pt }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\quotation}{\global\rightskip=\leftmargin}{\global\rightskip=0pt }{}{}%
  \fi
}
```

[image]

Comment: O.k., so I see now that the command redefinition I wanted to changed lived within another very long command definition, that's why my redefinition of  `eledmac`'s `\quote` command didn't work, as the version from the class file would overwrite when the `\initnumbering@sectcmd` is called by `\beginnumbering`. Your `\appto` instead adds three lines add the end of the `initnumbering@sectcmd` definition, which check if we're in a quotation I guess, I don't fully understand latex conditionals yet, and, if we are, patch the lines that set the right indents in `\quote` and `quotation`?

Comment: @muk.li The conditional `\ifnoquotation` is true if the `noquotation` option is passed to `eledmac`: in this case, no redefinition of `quote` and `quotation` is performed (which probably has the effect that numbering doesn't work). The lines I add to the `\initnumbering@sectcmd` patch the redefined `\quote` command. I tried patching directly `\initnumbering@sectcmd`, but didn't succeed, so I resorted to this method.